# Tab fragment is loading but not showing up

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, drawer

I have a fragment in Navigation Drawer project. It contains 7 tabs. When i clicked on tabs it should show fragment below the tabs. Fragment loads but does not show up.

Fragment code that contains the tabs can be found @ http://pastebin.com/SAARGWLh (FragmentLoadshedding.java)

and the fragment class code that should be displayed inside above fragment can be found @ http://pastebin.com/dnamPgBr (group1.java)

While i run the code and click on tabs 1,2 or any other the code inside group1.java is running but cannot load its content i.e. group1.xml.

Please suggest appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an absolutely light-weight and material design implementation of what you are asking for by Chris Banes (who's from the android team). Honestly, I tried looking at your code but it's too complicated for my taste. Using the example can help you create a bug free viewpager fragment inside a navigation drawer that is as vanilla as it can get.

The code for the implementation can be found here:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: This may be the last alternative. But, for now i have to struggle with my current codes to get the solution. Thanks!!

Comment: I'll try look into your code in detail once I'm home. Will comment here if I find something

Answer (score 0):

After hours of struggling i found the solution myself. There was problem in the layout file.

Comment: And what was the problem?